# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have Employee Class  like below

```
@Entity
public  class Employee{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
id;
Department dept;
Address add;
@JoinColumn(name = "manager_emp_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
Manager Employee;
//other fields and their getters and setters

}
```

when i call `entityManager.persist(Employee emp)` to persist i get below error

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist : com.myComp.Employee

i verfied employee.id is null or 0. **So i am not getting why its considering Employee as detached instance instead of transient ?**

Can it because its some member variable(instead of Employee) has id as non zero value and hibernate is trying to persist ? If yes
can i get which exact class is detached instance as there are many member variables?

Comment: In `Employee`, do you have a relation to another instance of `Employee` entity? Like a manager? Or, does any of other relations, like `dept`, has a relation to another `Employee` instance?

Comment: yes its there but its value is null. I have updated the Employee class in my post  to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing but:
manager is probably also Employee, when you set on your new Employ objcet the manager, most likely you are using existing one but that you did not retrieve it from the same EnityManger (or haven't marge it). And the exception. Without the your DAO code or other entities it is only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

> So i am not getting why its considering Employee as detached instance instead of transient ?

I cannot tell you either, because your code example is too brief (and also snytactically incorrect).

> Can it because its some member variable(instead of Employee) has id as non zero value and hibernate is trying to persist ?

Possibly.

> If yes can i get which exact class is detached instance as there are many member variables?

This you already have. Based on the exception you posted, it is an instance of Employee. Based on the given info I have to guess, that you have employee also reference itself (maybe via department?). If you are not cascading the persist operation you might hit this exception when one of the lower level employees is tried to be persisted. But as said, your sample is too brief and incomplete as to really give you a full fledged answer.

Comment: please see my updated question  for @JoinColumn(name = "manager_emp_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
Manager Employee;